# What is the technical term for this corner cupboard?

Tags: furniture, carpentry, terminology

I am trying to learn what this small blue cupboard on the left side of the table is called? It's a corner cupboard but I am not sure what the technical term is: [image]

Comment: "corner hutch"?

Comment: A corner cabinet?

Answer (score 4):

I am not certain what you mean by a "technical term" for it.  I would call it a ***corner hutch*** or a *corner display hutch* or maybe a *corner bookcase*.

Why *corner*? Because it is shaped to fit in a corner.

Why *hutch*? A hutch is sometimes something that sits on top of a bureau, table, desk, or other piece of flat-topped furniture. However, hutches can also be a free-standing shelved storage units with doors.  The impression people have of "hutch" will vary by region.

Why *bookcase*? It's got books on it.

I can tell you also that I would **not** call it

- a cabinet: Cabinets usually have doors and are wall-hung or sit on the floor.
- a cupboard: Cupboards are usually wall-hung and contain dishwares or foodstuffs
- a curio cabinet: these usually have mirrored backs and glass doors
- a display case: see curio cabinet. These usually have at least glass doors.